# refreshing data of app php vs java in android

Tags: java, php, android

I have an app that retrieves data over httpconnection just b calling a php script. I want to implement the following: enable notifications like facebook when new data arrives. I have found a way to do it but I am wondering if there is a better sollution. so far, my app is running in the background and fetches data all the time. I am wondering if it would be better any othrr approach (because I am always fetching data over http connection and I think that this is in-effective). Is there any other way? like enabling my app over my server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might make more sense to integrate GCM into your application. Have your server querying that data, and when it meets your criteria for a needed update on the client-side... send a GCM notification from your server to your client. When your client grabs that message... then run your 'update' calls.

More information for GCM can be found here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html

If you have more specific needs or functionality let me know, and I can help you work them in, in a less data-intensive way.

Comment: thanks!! it look like it is what I want. if i come into trouble I will let you know.